# Circle wrapped on a cylinder

Tags: circles, parametric

I'd like to know the parametric equations of a circle(r) wrapped on a cylinder(R).

$x(t)= r\times cos(t)$
$y(t)=?$
$z(t)=?$

Which are the parametric equations?
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a helix?  What have you tried?

Comment: You have to describe much more precisely what you have in mind.

Comment: Here's an sketch:
![circle wrapped on a cylinder](http://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/q71/45011_583137158415294_618752511_n.jpg)

Comment: Sorry Robert...  I wrote that answer before I saw the picture... I assumed it was a helix so I will delete...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are wrapping a unit disk of radius $r>0$ isometrically around a cylinder $Z$ of radius $R>0$. Let the axis of the cylinder be the $z$-axis.

Bevor the wrapping the disk lies in a $(s,z)$-plane and is determined by the condition
$$s^2+z^2\leq r^2\ .$$
Its boundary circle $\gamma$ has a parametric representation of the form
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto(s,z):=(r\cos t,r\sin t)\qquad(-\pi\leq t\leq\pi)\ .$$
The wrapping $f$ maps points $(s,z)$ onto points $(x,y,z)$  on $Z$ having the same $z$-coordinate and having a polar angle $\phi=\arg(x,y)$ such that $R\phi=s$. It follows that $f$ is given by
$$f:\quad (s,z)\mapsto\left(R\cos{s\over R},\ R\sin{s\over R},\ z\right)\ .$$
It follows that a parametric representation of the wrapped circle is given by
$$f\circ \gamma:\quad t\mapsto\left(R\cos{r\cos t\over R},\ R\sin{r\cos t\over R},\ r\sin t\right)\qquad(-\pi\leq t\leq\pi)\ .$$

Comment: Very nice! 
works perfectly.  
$x(t) = Rcos(rcos(t)/R)$  
$y(t) = Rsin(rcos(t)/R)$  
$z(t) = rsin(t)$ 

I just had to adjust because the cylinder axis is the $x$-axis. 
$x(t) = rcos(t)$  
$y(t) = Rsin(rsin(t)/R)$  
$z(t) = Rcos(rsin(t)/R)$